# Understanding of WebSockets

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, websocket

My understanding is that a socket corresponds to a network identifier, port and TCP identifier. [1]

Operating systems enable a process to be associated with a port (which IIUC is a way of making the process addressable on the network for inbound data).

So a WebSocket server will typically be associated with a port well-known for accepting and understanding HTTP for the upgrade request (like 443) and then use TCP identifiers to enable multiple network sockets to be open concurrently for a single server process and a single port.

Please can someone confirm or correct my understanding?

[1] *"To provide for unique names at
each TCP, we concatenate a NETWORK identifier, and a TCP identifier
with a port name to create a SOCKET name which will be unique
throughout all networks connected together."* https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc675

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When a client connects to your server on a given port, the client connection is coming from an IP address and a client-side port number.  The client-side port number is automatically generated by the client and will be unique for that client.  So, you end up with four items that make a connection.

```
Server IP address  (well known to all clients)
Server port        (well known to all clients)
Client IP address  (unique for that client)
Client port        (dynamically unique for that client and that socket)
```

So, it is the combination of these four items that make a unique TCP connection.  If the same client makes a second connection to the same server and port, then that second connection will have a different client port number (each connection a client makes will be given a different client port number) and thus the combination of those four items above will be different for that second client connection, allowing it's traffic to be completely separate from the first connection that client made.

So, a TCP socket is a unique combination of the four items above.  To see how that is used, let's look at how some traffic flows.

After a client connects to the server and a TCP socket is created to represent that connection, then the client sends a packet.  The packet is sent from the client IP address and from the unique client port number that that particular socket is using.  When the server receives that packet on its own port number, it can see that the packet is coming from the client IP address and from that particular client port number.  It can use these items to look up in its table and see which TCP socket this traffic is associated with and trigger an event for that particular socket.  This separates that client's traffic from all the other currently connected sockets (whether they are other connections from that same client or connections from other clients).

Now, the server wants to send a response to that client.  The packet is sent to the client's IP address and client port number.  The client TCP stack does the same thing.  It receives the packet from the server IP/port and addressed to the specific client port number and can then associate that packet with the appropriate TCP socket on the client so it can trigger an event on the right socket.

All traffic can uniquely be associated with the appropriate client or server TCP socket in this way, even though many clients may connect to the same server IP and port.  The uniqueness of the client IP/port allows both ends to tell which socket a given packet belongs to.

---

webSocket connections start out with an HTTP connection (which is a TCP socket running the HTTP protocol).  That initial HTTP request contains an "upgrade" header requesting the server to upgrade the protocol from HTTP to webSocket.  If the server agrees to the upgrade, then it returns a response that indicates that the protocol will be changed to the webSocket protocol.  The TCP socket remains the same, but both sides agree that they will now speak the webSocket protocol instead of the HTTP protocol.  So, once connected, you then have a TCP socket where both sides are speaking the webSocket protocol.  This TCP connection uses the same logic described above to remain unique from other TCP connections to the same server.

In this manner, you can have a single server on a single port that works for both HTTP connections and webSocket connections.  All connections to that server start out as HTTP connections, but some are converted to webSocket connections after both sides agree to change the protocol.  The HTTP connections that remain HTTP connections will be typical request/response and then the socket will be closed.  The HTTP connections that are "upgraded" to the webSocket protocol will remain open for the duration of the webSocket session (which can be long lived).  You can have many concurrent open webSocket connections that are all distinct from one another while new HTTP connections are regularly serviced all by the same server.  The TCP logic above is used to keep track of which packets to/from the same server/port belong to which connection.

---

FYI, you may have heard about NAT (Network Address Translation).  This is commonly used to allow private networks (like a home or corporate network) to interface to a public network (like the internet).  With NAT a server may see multiple clients as having the same client IP address even though they are physically different computers on a private network).  With NAT, multiple computers are routed through a common IP address, but NAT still guarantees that the client IP address and client port number are still a unique combination so the above scheme still works.  When using NAT an incoming packet destined for a particular client arrives at the shared IP address.  The IP/port is then translated to the actual client IP address and port number on the private network and then packet is forwarded to that device.  The server is generally unaware of this translation and packet forwarding.  Because the NAT server still maintains the uniqueness of the client IP/client port combination, the server's logic still works just fine even though it appears that many clients are sharing a common IP address).  Note, home network routes are usually configured to use NAT since all computers on the home network will "share" the one public IP address that your router has when accessing the internet.

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi - This answer describes the creation of one TCP socket connection that can be used for one webSocket connection.  Once you have that socket created, you can send as many messages as you want in either direction.  But, before you can send any info, you have to create the webSocket connection.  I'm not sure what else you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will not enable multiple sockets, there is no need for it. You will have multiple conections. It's a little different, but you undesrstand well. For UDP there's nothing to do, cause there is no connections.

In TCP, if two different machines connect to the same port on a third machine, there are two distinct connections because the source IPs differ. If the same machine (or two behind NAT or otherwise sharing the same IP address) connects twice to a single remote end, the connections are differentiated by source port, the same machine cannot open 2 connections on the same port.